# Spring Google OAuth2 With Refresh Token

Tags: spring-security, google-oauth, spring-oauth2

My current OAuth2 configuration doesn't return refresh token. My configuration is as basic as possible. How can I configure it so that it would return refresh_token as well.
I'm authenticating user on the server side. So JS solutions don't work.

I need the refresh token for RememberMe functionality. Specifically I'm using `oAuth2AuthorizedClientService.loadAuthorizedClient(clientId, principalName);` method, to get access to the information that was retrieved from googles authentication server.

```
 WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
 ...
 httpSecurity
        ...
          .and()
        .oauth2Login()
          .and()
        .rememberMe()
        ...
```

Application.yml:

```
security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          google:
            clientId: ZZZ
            clientSecret: zzzz
            redirectUri: https://example.com/login/oauth2/code/google
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution was to add [OAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#oauth2Client-authorization-request-resolver)

In `OAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver` I changed the `customAuthorizationRequest` (see below). Now it returns refresh token every time.

```
private OAuth2AuthorizationRequest customAuthorizationRequest( OAuth2AuthorizationRequest authorizationRequest) {

    Map<String, Object> additionalParameters =new LinkedHashMap<>(authorizationRequest.getAdditionalParameters());
    additionalParameters.put("access_type", "offline");

    return OAuth2AuthorizationRequest.from(authorizationRequest)
            .additionalParameters(additionalParameters)
            .build();
}
```

also updated my `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`

```
.oauth2Login()
    .authorizationEndpoint()
    .authorizationRequestResolver(
            new CustomAuthorizationRequestResolver(
                    this.clientRegistrationRepository))
    .and()
    .and()
.rememberMe()
```

if somebody finds simpler solution do post! :)

Comment: Could you please share the full code? i have a similar config but getting an issue. Factory method 'filterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: userDetailsService cannot be null. Invoke RememberMeConfigurer#userDetailsService(UserDetailsService) or see its javadoc for alternative approaches.