# Spring 5, OAuth2 with Google refresh access token after 401 return

Tags: java, spring-security, google-oauth, google-calendar-api, spring-oauth2

I have simple configured app

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.clientId=xyz
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.clientSecret=xyz
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.scope=email,profile,openid,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets
```

I login with http://localhost:8080/oauth2/authorization/google and save to google calendar normally.

Getting access token looks like:

```
private String getAccessToken() {
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    String accessToken = null;
    if (authentication.getClass().isAssignableFrom(OAuth2AuthenticationToken.class)) {
      OAuth2AuthenticationToken oauthToken = (OAuth2AuthenticationToken) authentication;
      String clientRegistrationId = oauthToken.getAuthorizedClientRegistrationId();
      OAuth2AuthorizedClient client = authorizedClientService.loadAuthorizedClient(
        clientRegistrationId, oauthToken.getName());
      accessToken = client.getAccessToken().getTokenValue();
    }
    return accessToken;
  }
```

`OAuth2AuthorizedClient` contains refresh token.

But after 1 hour access token expires and I don't know how to refresh it. Without relogin.

https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/errors#401_invalid_credentials says

> Get a new access token using the long-lived refresh token.

And I found this one [Spring Google OAuth2 With Refresh Token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58560201/spring-google-oauth2-with-refresh-token) but don't works for me.

A have also relogin message after 401 but it's not user-friendly.

Could you help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I cant help to much with Java but if you check this example https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/installed-java see how it uses FileDataStoreFactory the if you request off line access you will get a refresh token and the GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow can use that to load a new access toen when it needs

Comment: Have you tried following the Calendar API [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/java)?

Comment: Iamblichus, yes I did, I solved my problem as below. To authenticate with OAuth2 Google I use Spring built-in mechanism. It's recivies Access Token and Refresh Token then I use them to connect to Google Calendar via Google lib.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you DaImTo for the hint.

I changed my credential usage from

```
    Credential credential = new GoogleCredential().setAccessToken(tokenUtils.getAccessToken());
```

to

```
 private Calendar getClient() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
    HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();

    Credential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
      .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
      .setTransport(httpTransport)
      .setClientSecrets(clientId, clientSecret)
      .build()
      .setAccessToken(tokenUtils.getAccessToken())
      .setRefreshToken(tokenUtils.getRefreshToken());

    return new Calendar.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
      .setApplicationName("appname").build();
  }
```

and it WORKS!

But the app receives Refresh Token only if there is set `prompt` with value `select_account` or `consent`.
With value `none` or without `prompt` Refresh Token is always null  (`access_type=offline`).

It's also not user friendly, because application user has to choose google account every time...

Do you know some workaround?

EDIT:

```
public class TokenUtils {

  private final OAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService;

  public TokenUtils(OAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService) {
    this.authorizedClientService = authorizedClientService;
  }

  public String getAccessToken() {
    OAuth2AuthorizedClient client = getClient();
    return client.getAccessToken().getTokenValue();
  }

  public String getRefreshToken() {
    OAuth2AuthorizedClient client = getClient();
    return client.getRefreshToken().getTokenValue();
  }

  public OAuth2AuthorizedClient getClient() {
    OAuth2AuthenticationToken oauthToken = getOAuthToken();
    return authorizedClientService.loadAuthorizedClient(
      oauthToken.getAuthorizedClientRegistrationId(), oauthToken.getName());
  }

  private OAuth2AuthenticationToken getOAuthToken() {
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    if (authentication.getClass().isAssignableFrom(OAuth2AuthenticationToken.class)) {
      return (OAuth2AuthenticationToken) authentication;
    }
    throw new SecurityException("Authentication is not OAuth2AuthenticationToken");
  }
}
```

EDIT 2:

```
http
      .oauth2Login()
      .successHandler(new RedirectToPrevAuthSuccessHandler())
      .userInfoEndpoint()
      .oidcUserService(addRolesOidcUserService);
      .oidcUserService(addRolesOidcUserService)
      .and()
      .authorizationEndpoint()
      .authorizationRequestResolver(new AddParamsRequestResolver(
        this.clientRegistrationRepository))
    ;
```

and

```
public class AddParamsRequestResolver implements OAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver {

  private final OAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver defaultAuthorizationRequestResolver;

  public AddParamsRequestResolver(ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository) {
    this.defaultAuthorizationRequestResolver =
      new DefaultOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver(
        clientRegistrationRepository,
        OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.DEFAULT_AUTHORIZATION_REQUEST_BASE_URI);
  }

  @Override
  public OAuth2AuthorizationRequest resolve(HttpServletRequest request) {
    OAuth2AuthorizationRequest authorizationRequest =
      this.defaultAuthorizationRequestResolver.resolve(request);

    if (authorizationRequest != null) {
      return addParams(authorizationRequest);
    }
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public OAuth2AuthorizationRequest resolve(HttpServletRequest request, String clientRegistrationId) {
    OAuth2AuthorizationRequest authorizationRequest =
      this.defaultAuthorizationRequestResolver.resolve(
        request, clientRegistrationId);

    if (authorizationRequest != null) {
      return addParams(authorizationRequest);
    }
    return null;
  }

  private OAuth2AuthorizationRequest addParams(
    OAuth2AuthorizationRequest authorizationRequest) {

    Map<String, Object> additionalParameters =
      new LinkedHashMap<>(authorizationRequest.getAdditionalParameters());
    additionalParameters.put("access_type", "offline");
    additionalParameters.put("prompt", "consent");
//    additionalParameters.put("prompt", "select_account");
//    additionalParameters.put("prompt", "login");

    return OAuth2AuthorizationRequest.from(authorizationRequest)
      .additionalParameters(additionalParameters)
      .build();
  }
```

Comment: Maybe that's because of localhost... https://stackoverflow.com/a/14929345/13729723

Comment: what is tokenUtils?

Comment: @JoaquínL.Robles I added tokenUtils to the post. up.

Comment: @Dalmto How can we do the same in latest versions of google library - GoogleCredential is deprecated.

Comment: thanks @wojek, I added the client reference but client.getRefreshToken() is always null, what's missing?

Comment: You have to set `prompt` parameter with value `select_account` or `consent`. In Spring Security I did it like above (EDIT 2).